# String Hive function for split key-value pair into two columns

Tags: scala

How to split this data T_32_P_1_A_420_H_60_R_0.30841494477846165_S_0 into two columns using hive function
For example

> T 32
>
> P 1
>
> A 420
>
> H 60
>
> R 0.30841494477846165
>
> S 0

Comment: You can make your own function...

Comment: Why the "scala" tag if you want a "hive" answer? And why the duplicate post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34307534/is-there-any-built-in-function-to-change-the-decoded-output-to-another-format-in ?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a regex implementation:

```
def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val s = "T_32_P_1_A_420_H_60_R_0.30841494477846165_S_0"
    val pattern = "[A-Z]\\_\\d+\\.?\\d*"
    var buff = new String()
    val r = Pattern.compile(pattern)
    val m = r.matcher(s)
    while (m.find()) {
      buff = buff + (m.group(0))
      buff = buff + "\n"
    }
    buff = buff.toString.replaceAll("\\_", " ")
    println("output:\n" + buff)
  }
```

**Output:**

```
output:
T 32
P 1
A 420
H 60
R 0.30841494477846165
S 0
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need to collect the data for further processing, *and* you're guaranteed it's always paired correctly, you could do something like this.

```
scala> val str = "T_32_P_1_A_420_H_60_R_0.30841494477846165_S_0"
str: String = T_32_P_1_A_420_H_60_R_0.30841494477846165_S_0

scala> val data = str.split("_").sliding(2,2)
data: Iterator[Array[String]] = non-empty iterator

scala> data.toList   // just to see it
res29: List[Array[String]] = List(Array(T, 32), Array(P, 1), Array(A, 420), Array(H, 60), Array(R, 0.30841494477846165), Array(S, 0))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can split your string, get an array, zipWithIndex and filter based on index to get two arrays col1 and col2 and then use it for printing:

```
val str = "T_32_P_1_A_420_H_60_R_0.30841494477846165_S_0"
val tmp = str.split('_').zipWithIndex
val col1 = tmp.filter( p => p._2 % 2 == 0 ).map( p => p._1)
val col2 = tmp.filter( p => p._2 % 2 != 0 ).map( p => p._1)

//col1: Array[String] = Array(T, P, A, H, R, S)
//col2: Array[String] = Array(32, 1, 420, 60, ...
```